# How to know whether a driver is a pseudo driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Are there any specificities in the Linux kernel API that allows one to identify whether a driver is a pseudo-driver?

Generally put, how can I know whether a driver module implementation is a pseudo-driver?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to know?  That is, to what use will such knowledge be applied?

Comment: I am analyzing some properties of the Linux kernel source code, and this is a type of variable that I need to control in my study. For example, is intuitive to believe that pseudo drivers should be allowed to have more ifdefs elsewhere that would test for their presence (to a certain degree, they are a base code for other drivers), instead of concrete device drivers, which target specific hardware, and thus, are vendor-specific.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by a 'pseudo driver'. Sounds like you're referring to [bus types](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/bus.txt).

Comment: A pseudo driver is a driver for which you don't have a physical device http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Pseudo-devices

Comment: Maybe one way is to verify whether the probe function is implemented in the driver. I don't see a need of a probe function in a pseudo-driver, as there is no hardware to probe for.

Comment: no interrupt handler could be some character, but some real device drivers also don't have interrupt handler.